# matrix multiplication in prolog

Tags: matrix, prolog, clpfd

I found a code that multiplicates matrixes.

```
% SWI-Prolog has transpose/2 in its clpfd library
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

% N is the dot product of lists V1 and V2.
dot(V1, V2, N) :- maplist(product,V1,V2,P), sumlist(P,N).
product(N1,N2,N3) :- N3 is N1*N2.

% Matrix multiplication with matrices represented
% as lists of lists. M3 is the product of M1 and M2
mmult(M1, M2, M3) :- transpose(M2,MT), maplist(mm_helper(MT), M1, M3).
mm_helper(M2, I1, M3) :- maplist(dot(I1), M2, M3).
```

If I type: `mult([[1,2],[3,4]],[[5,6],[7,8]],X).` then I get   `X = [[19, 22], [43, 50]].`

But how I can get a `X =  [[1*5+2*7, 1*6+2*8], [3*5+4*7, 3*6+4*8]] .`

P.S. I am new to prolog.
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is easy: Instead of evaluating the arithmetic expressions with is/2, simply leave them unevaluated and use the compound terms instead of their numerical values. I do it for product/3: Instead of

```
product(N1,N2,N3) :- N3 is N1*N2.
```

I write:

```
product(N1, N2, N1*N2).
```

You only need to write a corresponding version of sumlist/2.

Comment: how should I change sumlist/2?

Comment: In analogy to the change I showed you: Take sumlist/2, and instead of evaluating the arithmetic expression with is/2, represent the sum itself as a term (this time using the functor + instead of *).

Comment: Just write your own version of `sumlist`, but use `=` instead of `is`.